# How to put a list of values on a single axis and add custom labels

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling

I have a table in the following format:
Apple 2
Pear 3
Banana 5
Orange 6.5 
....
I would like to put the values on a single horizontal axis and add corresponding descriptive labels (apple, pear, banana etc.) next to the values. How can I do that in Mathematica? Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to look up [BarChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart.html).

Comment: What do you mean by *put the values on a single horizontal axis*? It sound like you want a dot on a line with a label. That's not the BarChart Jens suggested. Could you be a little bit more specific?

Answer (score 5):

From a list like `ls = {{"Apple", 2} , {"Pear", 3}, {"Banana", 5}, {"Orange", 6.5}}` you can get:

```
ListPlot[Labeled[{#[[2]], 0},Framed[Rotate[#[[1]], 90 Degree],
Background -> Yellow], Top] & /@ ls, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Using `ListPlot` with `Callout`:

```
ls = {{"Apple", 2} , {"Pear", 3}, {"Banana", 5}, {"Orange", 6.5}};

ListPlot[Callout[{#2, 0}, #, Above, 
    Background -> LightOrange, Frame -> True, FrameMargins -> 6, 
    "CalloutStyle" -> Red, LeaderSize -> 30, 
    LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Red}, 
    CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[.05]] & @@@ ls, Axes -> {True, False},
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], AspectRatio -> (1/4)]
```

[image]

(Ab)using `TimelinePlot`:

```
TimelinePlot[Labeled[{2000, 1, 1, #2}, # ] & @@@ ls, DateTicksFormat -> {"HourShort"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to do it yourself:

```
ls = {{"Apple", 2}, {"Pear", 3}, {"Banana", 5}, {"Orange", 6.5}};
Graphics[{
  {Text[Style[First@#, 18], {Last@#, 0.25}],
     Red,
     Disk[{Last@#, 0.1}, .05]} & /@ ls,
  },
 Axes -> { True, False}]
```

[image: single axis diagram]